# Activeadmin how to add sidebar to show with record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to add sidebars to some of the show pages in ActiveAdmin, I have the following, which works:

```
sidebar :users, :only => :show do
  "Hello, World"
end
```

but I'd like to access the particular record so that I can put data in the sidebar relevant to the record that is being viewed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `show` action you should normally have access to a User object, in the `@user` instance variable, so you could do something like

```
sidebar :users, :only => :show do
  render 'user'
end
```

and in the partial `app/views/admin/users/_user.html.erb` put the relevant data you want to show.